# Trying to use Holt-Winters to fit this data

Tags: r, time-series

I'm trying to fit the data in this message (daily temperatures) using the Holt–Winters technique in R, but can't get the seasonal example in [here](http://a-little-book-of-r-for-time-series.readthedocs.org/en/latest/src/timeseries.html) to work. Is this not possible with these data, or am I doing something wrong? The data are sampled every 10 minutes, so 144 points should correspond to one day.

My code is:

```
> time<-scan("timeseries.dat")
```

Read 2160 items:

```
> timets<-ts(time,frequency=144)
> hwOut<-HoltWinters(timets)

Warning message:
In HoltWinters(timets) :
  optimization difficulties: ERROR: ABNORMAL_TERMINATION_IN_LNSRCH
enter code here
```

The data are below. Thanks for any help you can offer.

```
17.17
16.49
15.81
15.47
15.36
15.29
15.22
15.15
15.15
15.15
15.15
15.65
16.23
16.59
15.59
15.05
14.95
14.95
14.95
14.95
14.89
14.83
14.85
15.62
15.63
14.95
14.87
14.84
14.85
15.39
15.36
14.74
14.71
14.82
14.95
14.95
14.95
14.95
15.01
15.08
15.15
15.3
15.37
15.36
15.41
15.58
15.87
15.87
15.91
16.08
16.49
16.85
17.01
16.62
16.55
16.7
16.68
16.76
16.9
16.97
17.04
17.11
17.1
17.2
17.42
17.49
17.55
17.62
17.69
17.76
17.83
17.9
17.96
18.03
18.12
18.14
18.14
18.14
18.14
18.14
18.2
18.23
18.24
18.45
18.65
18.86
18.95
18.96
18.96
19.1
19.2
19.27
19.41
19.48
19.47
19.62
19.65
19.58
19.65
19.72
19.78
19.78
19.78
19.78
19.73
19.62
19.47
19.49
19.35
19.06
18.94
18.7
18.34
18.22
18.04
17.83
17.62
17.42
17.21
17.07
16.94
16.8
16.73
16.63
16.49
16.65
16.68
16.59
16.45
16.38
16.39
16.33
16.25
16.18
16.11
16.05
15.98
15.84
15.73
15.67
15.65
15.76
16.08
16.61
16.55
15.46
15.11
15.57
16.59
16.7
16.66
16.59
16.6
16.27
15.36
15.45
15.38
15.15
14.62
14.39
14.33
14.19
14.09
14.02
13.95
13.89
13.82
14.67
14.62
13.72
13.64
13.57
13.51
13.51
13.51
13.51
13.66
13.73
13.72
13.78
13.88
14.02
14.02
14.06
14.23
14.6
14.79
14.85
14.99
15.02
14.85
14.99
15.53
16.39
16.31
16.39
16.59
16.49
16.67
17.11
17.29
17.39
17.46
17.53
17.6
17.67
17.9
18.04
18.11
18.25
18.44
18.66
18.82
18.92
18.99
19.13
19.25
19.31
19.3
19.35
19.42
19.49
19.65
19.97
19.88
19.93
20.08
20.15
20.23
20.3
20.3
20.35
20.51
20.35
20.39
20.62
20.63
20.59
20.51
20.67
20.7
20.62
20.63
20.54
20.3
20.39
20.33
20.19
20.11
20.11
20.19
19.96
19.82
19.75
19.53
19.33
19.2
19.33
19.15
18.77
18.46
18.23
18.11
18.04
17.93
17.78
17.71
17.64
17.57
17.73
17.72
17.57
17.48
17.48
17.57
17.49
17.52
17.67
17.53
17.42
17.35
17.36
17.31
17.24
17.17
17.07
16.91
17.75
17.65
16.69
16.43
16.33
16.26
16.19
16.09
15.93
15.85
15.8
15.82
16.65
16.6
15.71
15.55
15.45
15.38
15.39
15.34
15.27
15.2
15.12
15.05
16
16.1
15.71
15.22
15.01
15.05
14.98
14.94
15.05
15.78
15.91
15.49
15.56
15.64
15.71
15.78
15.9
16.15
16.19
16.45
16.91
17.26
17.39
17.46
17.53
17.68
18
18.15
18.29
18.44
18.8
19.14
19.42
19.65
19.82
19.97
20.19
20.41
20.62
20.79
20.82
20.73
20.88
21.02
21.17
21.32
21.43
21.39
21.2
21.21
21.28
21.35
21.41
21.39
21.23
21.17
21.17
21.1
21.02
20.95
20.95
20.91
20.84
20.99
21.1
21.17
21.24
21.3
21.28
21.12
21.05
21.06
20.97
20.95
20.95
20.95
20.93
20.84
20.77
20.71
20.73
20.81
20.85
20.84
20.92
20.93
20.84
20.93
20.85
20.62
20.62
20.62
20.62
20.4
20.36
20.51
20.22
19.96
19.75
19.68
19.54
19.31
19.41
19.29
18.99
18.92
18.84
18.77
18.76
18.86
19.09
18.8
18.58
18.55
18.7
18.84
18.99
18.98
19.05
19.2
19.31
19.27
19.2
19.13
18.77
17.78
17.52
17.42
17.35
17.28
17.21
17.24
17.8
18.31
18.44
17.76
17.31
17.13
17.13
17.13
17.13
17.13
17.11
17.02
18.01
18.01
17.13
16.97
16.86
16.8
16.8
16.8
16.8
16.63
16.72
17.13
17.21
17.24
17.24
17.62
17.82
17.89
18.04
18.18
18.33
18.34
18.39
18.55
18.37
18.38
18.55
18.78
18.95
19.09
19.24
19.36
19.42
19.57
19.68
19.75
19.98
20.06
19.97
20.13
20.23
20.3
20.37
20.33
20.08
20.06
20.12
20.19
20.19
20.19
20.19
20.35
20.4
20.4
20.4
20.42
20.51
20.42
20.49
20.73
20.74
20.7
20.62
20.95
21
20.84
20.83
20.88
20.95
20.88
20.8
20.73
20.9
20.89
20.73
20.64
20.63
20.73
20.98
21.04
20.95
20.96
20.92
20.84
20.85
20.78
20.62
20.55
20.42
20.19
20.21
20.1
19.86
19.55
19.32
19.2
19.14
19.02
18.88
18.73
18.6
18.55
18.63
18.67
18.66
18.58
18.55
18.55
18.48
18.43
18.44
18.29
18.19
18.22
18.37
18.49
18.55
18.55
18.55
18.55
18.4
18.32
18.33
18.25
18.22
18.22
18.14
18.11
18.11
18.03
18
18
17.93
17.85
17.78
17.71
17.68
17.78
17.79
17.75
17.67
17.74
17.79
17.78
17.62
17.57
17.57
17.57
17.59
17.67
17.6
17.58
17.67
17.91
18.04
18.11
18.18
18.23
18.22
18.39
18.44
18.44
18.44
18.44
18.44
18.59
18.63
18.55
18.78
18.95
19.09
19.24
19.35
19.42
19.64
19.86
20.08
20.16
20.25
20.4
20.63
20.78
20.84
21.07
21.23
21.28
21.2
21.2
21.28
21.2
21.2
21.28
21.2
21.2
21.28
21.13
21.04
21.06
21.21
21.33
21.39
21.28
21.37
21.61
21.94
22.08
22.15
22.22
22.32
22.48
22.53
22.7
22.92
23.15
23.31
23.46
23.61
23.54
22.81
22.35
22.26
22.26
22.26
22.29
22.37
22.22
22.11
22.04
21.89
21.81
21.82
21.6
21.5
21.5
21.28
21.06
20.84
20.62
20.48
20.51
20.28
20.14
20.08
20.1
19.96
19.64
19.48
19.39
19.31
19.16
19.02
18.88
18.94
19
18.99
18.92
18.84
18.77
18.7
18.68
18.77
18.54
18.39
18.33
18.34
18.24
18
18.01
17.93
17.78
17.87
17.82
17.67
17.59
17.57
17.57
17.49
17.46
17.46
17.37
17.35
17.35
17.35
17.35
17.35
17.27
17.24
17.24
17.24
17.24
17.24
17.17
17.13
17.13
17.06
17.02
17.02
16.87
16.76
16.69
16.62
16.51
16.36
16.34
16.4
16.47
16.47
16.47
16.47
16.47
16.47
16.47
16.54
16.59
16.58
16.75
16.8
16.8
16.8
16.8
16.8
16.87
16.9
16.91
17.06
17.2
17.35
17.62
17.93
18.22
18.3
18.39
18.55
18.77
18.99
19.2
19.42
19.66
19.97
20.2
20.34
20.4
20.7
20.96
21.17
21.23
21.38
21.61
21.92
22.07
22.04
22.13
22.15
22.15
22.15
22.24
22.48
22.48
22.48
22.48
22.48
22.43
22.26
22.35
22.3
22.15
22.15
22.15
22.15
22.15
22.15
22.15
22.1
21.94
21.72
21.57
21.43
21.28
21.22
21.04
20.73
20.5
20.31
20.19
20.21
20.12
19.97
19.82
19.68
19.53
19.46
19.35
19.2
19.06
18.89
18.66
18.67
18.59
18.44
18.37
18.29
18.22
18.15
18.07
18
18
17.94
17.78
17.9
17.79
17.57
17.35
17.18
17.13
16.98
17.01
17.35
17.25
16.93
16.58
16.51
16.43
16.36
16.29
16.24
16.26
16.74
16.72
16.15
16.14
16.17
16.26
16.61
16.95
17.13
16.38
15.92
15.82
15.92
15.86
15.71
15.72
15.67
15.6
15.6
15.57
15.49
15.54
15.71
15.93
15.93
15.93
15.93
15.93
15.97
16.15
16.31
16.4
16.47
16.54
16.57
16.47
16.53
16.65
16.8
16.86
16.98
17.13
17.28
17.34
17.24
17.53
17.76
17.89
17.89
17.93
18
17.99
17.97
17.99
18.17
18.35
18.53
18.56
18.74
18.98
19.25
19.37
19.34
19.34
19.39
19.52
19.46
19.41
19.43
19.55
19.67
19.79
19.97
20.14
20.24
20.12
20.03
19.97
19.83
19.79
19.79
19.79
19.71
19.52
19.58
19.64
19.7
19.76
19.84
19.97
20.09
20.17
20.06
19.87
19.75
19.7
19.5
19.41
19.43
19.5
19.45
19.25
19.18
19.16
19.16
18.71
18.48
18.44
18.45
18.41
18.35
18.29
18.23
18.17
18.23
18.26
18.26
18.34
18.32
18.26
18.2
18.24
18.53
18.56
18.47
18.35
18.22
18.14
18.08
18.02
17.97
17.99
18.47
18.44
17.9
17.75
17.72
17.72
17.73
17.7
17.63
17.57
17.51
17.45
17.93
17.92
17.45
17.3
17.33
17.45
17.38
17.36
17.36
17.31
17.28
17.36
17.7
17.68
17.28
17.22
17.16
17.1
17.04
16.99
17.01
17.07
17.07
17.01
17.07
17.13
17.19
17.3
17.39
17.45
17.58
17.61
17.54
17.6
17.66
17.72
17.78
17.85
17.99
18.26
18.34
18.26
18.25
18.34
18.53
18.53
18.53
18.53
18.65
18.74
18.8
18.86
18.95
19.07
19.07
19.07
19.07
19.19
19.28
19.34
19.4
19.46
19.52
19.47
19.42
19.43
19.55
19.6
19.52
19.79
19.83
19.7
19.68
19.73
19.79
19.85
19.86
19.79
19.85
19.91
19.97
20.03
20.08
20.06
19.9
19.94
20.06
20.18
20.2
19.97
19.95
20.07
20.24
20.12
20
19.88
19.88
19.85
19.79
19.73
19.63
19.43
19.31
19.19
19.07
19.01
18.95
18.89
18.83
18.77
18.71
18.59
18.48
18.44
18.5
18.56
18.62
18.56
18.55
18.62
18.53
18.61
18.8
18.94
18.98
18.89
18.7
18.61
18.62
18.5
18.38
18.26
18.88
18.89
18.44
18.25
18.1
18.08
18.72
19.29
19.61
19.58
19.01
17.99
18.42
18.32
17.9
17.85
17.75
17.63
17.63
17.6
17.54
17.54
17.54
17.54
17.87
17.88
17.54
17.56
17.48
17.36
17.29
17.28
17.28
17.28
17.28
17.28
17.39
17.44
17.36
17.63
17.7
17.63
17.69
17.75
17.81
17.81
17.83
17.9
18.18
18.22
18.08
17.99
18.02
18.08
18.14
18.24
18.44
18.36
18.41
18.53
18.65
18.77
18.89
19.01
19.1
19.15
19.28
19.37
19.43
19.56
19.65
19.71
19.83
19.95
20.08
20.08
20.1
20.17
20.29
20.41
20.54
20.66
20.83
21.09
21.11
21.06
21
21.2
21.2
21
21.06
21.12
21.19
20.92
20.84
20.91
20.92
20.89
20.82
20.9
20.85
20.72
20.66
20.6
20.54
20.42
20.29
20.17
20.04
19.92
19.8
19.75
19.65
19.52
19.4
19.31
19.25
19
18.79
18.6
18.41
18.27
18.23
18.1
18
17.95
17.95
17.93
17.86
17.85
17.94
18.14
17.89
17.73
17.67
17.47
17.39
17.4
17.34
17.28
17.21
17.15
17.13
17.21
17.23
17.16
17.03
16.97
16.91
16.84
16.78
16.72
16.66
16.65
16.69
16.75
16.69
16.63
16.57
16.58
16.54
16.47
16.41
16.39
16.47
16.41
16.37
16.38
16.46
16.44
16.38
16.31
16.28
16.29
16.29
16.29
16.29
16.34
16.41
16.47
16.47
16.5
16.57
16.57
16.59
16.66
16.86
16.98
17.03
17.02
17.08
17.21
17.2
17.24
17.31
17.37
17.4
17.4
17.52
17.64
17.77
17.96
18.03
17.95
18.01
18.07
18.14
18.39
18.58
18.69
18.77
18.74
18.6
18.52
18.53
18.6
18.6
18.6
18.6
18.6
18.68
18.97
18.95
19.06
19.25
19.38
19.43
19.43
19.79
20.15
20.35
20.29
20.23
20.17
20.15
20.29
20.63
20.59
20.46
20.26
20.85
20.83
20.45
20.18
20.01
19.89
19.77
19.6
19.34
19.29
19.17
18.97
18.65
18.43
18.32
18.25
18.25
18.32
17.96
17.67
17.67
18.34
18.61
18.32
17.64
17.29
17.12
17
16.89
16.84
16.99
16.95
16.75
16.68
16.66
16.66
16.61
16.44
16.1
16.11
16.01
15.83
15.85
15.74
15.55
15.39
15.36
15.36
15.36
15.33
15.27
16.18
16.93
17.12
16.74
16.11
15.46
15.45
15.4
15.27
15.42
15.35
15.09
15.03
14.97
14.9
14.84
14.78
14.72
14.6
14.5
14.53
15.23
15.22
14.53
14.47
14.41
14.35
14.35
14.32
14.26
14.31
14.41
14.53
14.4
14.35
14.35
14.35
14.35
14.35
14.7
15.04
15.27
15.43
15.46
15.46
15.46
15.5
15.64
15.69
15.82
16.01
16.07
16.13
16.2
16.26
16.36
16.57
16.67
16.92
17.31
17.62
17.92
18.23
18.11
18.14
18.41
18.11
18.18
18.51
18.56
18.73
18.97
18.79
18.61
18.51
18.94
19.25
19.43
19.57
19.63
19.62
19.72
19.92
20.17
20.17
20.23
20.35
20.28
20.32
20.45
20.32
20.21
20.17
20.23
20.29
20.35
20.37
20.25
19.98
19.98
19.97
19.89
19.59
19.28
19.06
19.11
19.17
19.15
18.97
18.78
18.6
18.53
18.48
18.41
18.12
17.82
17.58
17.4
17.19
16.94
16.75
16.58
16.47
16.48
16.41
16.29
16.24
16.14
16.01
15.89
15.75
15.55
15.41
15.35
15.36
15.24
15.15
15.09
14.96
14.84
14.72
14.51
14.41
14.35
14.29
14.2
14.07
14.01
13.95
13.89
13.76
13.69
13.7
13.64
13.58
13.52
13.45
13.41
13.42
13.3
13.2
13.15
13.22
13.19
13.05
13.13
13.13
13.05
12.91
12.87
12.87
12.87
12.88
12.96
13.29
13.46
13.52
13.64
13.73
13.79
13.98
14.11
14.16
14.41
14.6
14.72
15.03
15.29
15.46
15.44
15.57
15.83
15.97
16.04
16.1
16.16
16.33
16.75
17.07
17.31
17.49
17.75
17.95
18.14
18.34
18.55
18.78
18.91
18.99
19.04
18.96
19.02
19.21
19.32
19.5
19.8
19.84
20.04
20.4
20.6
20.66
20.65
20.69
20.82
20.99
21.11
21.2
21.25
21.16
21.23
21.42
21.7
21.74
21.67
21.62
21.54
21.42
21.49
21.38
21.08
20.95
20.88
20.82
20.77
20.71
20.65
20.54
20.45
20.4
20.29
20.2
20.14
19.91
19.74
19.63
19.47
19.24
18.95
18.83
18.75
18.7
18.33
18.16
18.1
18.05
17.93
17.67
17.99
17.92
17.5
17.57
17.59
17.59
17.73
17.68
17.42
17.25
17.31
17.42
17.53
17.6
17.5
17.45
17.41
17.42
17.37
17.28
17.16
17.16
17.11
16.99
17.07
17.05
16.99
16.94
16.9
16.91
16.98
16.95
16.82
16.75
16.74
16.74
16.74
16.74
16.74
16.68
16.64
16.65
16.71
16.77
16.82
16.81
16.85
16.91
16.96
17.02
17.08
17.19
17.28
17.33
17.44
17.55
17.59
17.41
17.32
17.33
17.39
17.45
17.5
17.67
17.83
17.93
17.74
17.7
17.76
17.77
17.73
17.67
17.74
17.76
17.76
17.76
17.82
18.1
18.33
18.55
18.78
18.96
19.13
19.29
19.4
19.52
19.63
19.74
19.84
19.89
19.88
19.94
20.06
20.13
20.14
20.14
20.14
20.18
20.31
20.31
20.34
20.4
20.4
20.42
20.48
20.48
20.5
20.57
20.38
20.34
20.4
20.34
20.28
20.23
20.27
20.36
20.48
20.5
20.41
20.23
20.23
20.2
20.14
20.14
20.1
19.97
20.05
19.9
19.46
19.35
19.21
19.04
18.98
18.87
18.7
18.65
18.53
18.36
18.24
18.15
18.1
17.92
17.84
17.85
17.91
17.87
17.67
17.75
17.68
17.5
17.46
17.34
17.16
17.11
17.02
16.91
16.85
16.76
16.65
16.6
16.54
16.48
17.25
17.23
16.48
16.35
16.28
16.23
16.23
16.18
16.06
16.06
16.06
16.06
16.19
16.17
15.97
15.88
16.25
17.25
17.32
17.33
17.33
17.4
17.1
16.06
15.73
15.57
15.46
15.38
15.4
15.46
15.52
15.55
15.55
15.7
15.91
16.14
16.14
16.19
16.31
16.37
16.46
16.65
16.94
17.2
17.42
17.63
17.65
17.5
17.32
17.23
17.25
17.3
17.38
17.5
17.56
17.63
17.76
17.93
18.1
18.27
18.5
18.66
18.7
18.95
19.01
18.87
18.99
19.06
19.12
19.29
19.46
19.63
19.8
19.91
19.89
20.19
20.37
20.4
20.34
20.28
20.23
20.17
20.18
20.4
20.52
20.58
20.57
20.7
20.73
20.65
20.51
20.51
20.57
20.63
20.62
20.48
20.42
20.4
20.4
20.28
20.25
20.31
20.26
20.2
20.14
20.09
20.03
19.97
19.87
19.73
19.55
19.32
19.1
18.87
18.81
18.65
18.36
18.3
18.22
18.1
17.86
17.7
17.59
17.48
17.34
17.16
17.17
17.08
16.91
16.85
16.79
16.74
16.57
16.45
16.4
16.21
16.1
16.06
16.06
16.04
15.97
15.86
15.74
15.63
15.57
15.5
15.38
15.38
15.33
15.21
15.34
15.35
15.29
15.29
15.27
15.21
15.21
15.16
15.04
15.05
15.01
14.95
14.89
14.88
14.95
14.95
14.95
14.95
14.95
14.95
14.95
15.06
15.16
15.21
15.21
15.24
15.38
15.66
15.91
16.06
16.11
16.19
16.31
16.36
16.49
16.74
17.06
17.2
17.25
17.3
17.29
17.16
17.33
17.48
17.59
17.57
17.71
18.02
18.2
18.33
18.44
18.61
18.78
18.87
18.87
18.87
18.87
18.8
18.84
19.04
19.08
19.18
19.29
19.4
19.48
19.46
19.58
19.66
19.72
19.77
19.81
19.8
19.86
19.9
19.89
20.08
20.12
20.06
20.05
20.08
20.14
20.09
20.05
20.06
20.17
20.27
20.31
20.13
20.08
20.14
20.03
19.91
19.8
19.91
19.97
19.97
19.97
19.99
20.06
20.11
20.16
20.14
20.04
19.9
19.72
19.37
19.14
19.04
18.67
18.47
18.44
18.51
18.53
18.53
18.53
18.41
18.02
17.95
17.92
17.93
18.05
18.11
18.1
18.04
18.13
18.44
18.19
18.09
18.1
18.17
18.12
17.93
17.99
```

Comment: Using Holt-Winters with frequency of 144 is a bad idea. Use a more parsimonious model such as tbats() from the forecast package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, you didn't create your `time` variable correctly. The following code works just fine for me:

```
>   x=c(17.17,16.49,15.81,15.47,15.36,15.29,15.22,15.15,15.15,15.15,15.15,15.65,16.23,16.59,15.59,15.05,14.95,14.95,14.95,14.95,14.89,14.83,14.85,15.62,
    + 15.63,14.95,14.87,14.84,14.85,15.39,15.36,14.74,14.71,14.82,14.95,14.95,14.95,14.95,15.01,15.08,15.15,15.3,15.37,15.36,15.41,15.58,15.87,15.87,15.91,
    + 16.08,16.49,16.85,17.01,16.62,16.55,16.7,16.68,16.76,16.9,16.97,17.04,17.11,17.1,17.2,17.42,17.49,17.55,17.62,17.69,17.76,17.83,17.9,17.96,18.03,18.12,
    + 18.14,18.14,18.14,18.14,18.14,18.2,18.23,18.24,18.45,18.65,18.86,18.95,18.96,18.96,19.1,19.2,19.27,19.41,19.48,19.47,19.62,19.65,19.58,19.65,19.72,
    + 19.78,19.78,19.78,19.78,19.73,19.62,19.47,19.49,19.35,19.06,18.94,18.7,18.34,18.22,18.04,17.83,17.62,17.42,17.21,17.07,16.94,16.8,16.73,16.63,16.49,
    + 16.65,16.68,16.59,16.45,16.38,16.39,16.33,16.25,16.18,16.11,16.05,15.98,15.84,15.73,15.67,15.65,15.76,16.08,16.61,16.55,15.46,15.11,15.57,16.59,16.7,
    + 16.66,16.59,16.6,16.27,15.36,15.45,15.38,15.15,14.62,14.39,14.33,14.19,14.09,14.02,13.95,13.89,13.82,14.67,14.62,13.72,13.64,13.57,13.51,13.51,13.51,
    + 13.51,13.66,13.73,13.72,13.78,13.88,14.02,14.02,14.06,14.23,14.6,14.79,14.85,14.99,15.02,14.85,14.99,15.53,16.39,16.31,16.39,16.59,16.49,16.67,17.11,
    + 17.29,17.39,17.46,17.53,17.6,17.67,17.9,18.04,18.11,18.25,18.44,18.66,18.82,18.92,18.99,19.13,19.25,19.31,19.3,19.35,19.42,19.49,19.65,19.97,19.88,
    + 19.93,20.08,20.15,20.23,20.3,20.3,20.35,20.51,20.35,20.39,20.62,20.63,20.59,20.51,20.67,20.7,20.62,20.63,20.54,20.3,20.39,20.33,20.19,20.11,20.11,
    + 20.19,19.96,19.82,19.75,19.53,19.33,19.2,19.33,19.15,18.77,18.46,18.23,18.11,18.04,17.93,17.78,17.71,17.64,17.57,17.73,17.72,17.57,17.48,17.48,17.57,
    + 17.49,17.52,17.67,17.53,17.42,17.35,17.36,17.31,17.24,17.17,17.07,16.91,17.75,17.65,16.69,16.43,16.33,16.26,16.19,16.09,15.93,15.85,15.8,15.82,16.65,
    + 16.6,15.71,15.55,15.45,15.38,15.39,15.34,15.27,15.2,15.12,15.05,16,16.1,15.71,15.22,15.01,15.05,14.98,14.94,15.05,15.78,15.91,15.49,15.56,15.64,15.71,15.78,15.9,16.15,16.19,16.45,16.91,17.26,17.39,17.46,17.53,17.68,18,18.15,18.29,18.44,18.8,19.14,19.42,19.65,19.82,19.97,20.19,20.41,20.62,20.79,20.82,20.73,20.88,21.02,21.17,21.32,21.43,21.39,21.2,21.21,21.28,21.35,21.41,21.39,21.23,21.17,21.17,21.1,21.02,20.95,20.95,20.91,20.84,20.99,21.1,21.17,21.24,21.3,21.28,21.12,21.05,21.06,20.97,20.95,20.95,20.95,20.93,20.84,20.77,20.71,20.73,20.81,20.85,20.84,20.92,20.93,20.84,20.93,20.85,20.62,20.62,20.62,20.62,20.4,20.36,20.51,20.22,19.96,19.75,19.68,19.54,19.31,19.41,19.29,18.99,18.92,18.84,18.77,18.76,18.86,19.09,18.8,18.58,18.55,18.7,18.84,18.99,18.98,19.05,19.2,19.31,19.27,19.2,19.13,18.77,17.78,17.52,17.42,17.35,17.28,17.21,17.24,17.8,18.31,18.44,17.76,17.31,17.13,17.13,17.13,17.13,17.13,17.11,17.02,18.01,18.01,17.13,16.97,16.86,16.8,16.8,16.8,16.8,16.63,16.72,17.13,17.21,17.24,17.24,17.62,17.82,17.89,18.04,18.18,18.33,18.34,18.39,18.55,18.37,18.38,18.55,18.78,18.95,19.09,19.24,19.36,19.42,19.57,19.68,19.75,19.98,20.06,19.97,20.13,20.23,20.3,20.37,20.33,20.08,
    + 20.06,20.12,20.19,20.19,20.19,20.19,20.35,20.4,20.4,20.4,20.42,20.51,20.42,20.49,20.73,20.74,20.7,20.62,20.95,21,20.84,20.83,20.88,20.95,20.88,20.8,
    + 20.73,20.9,20.89,20.73,20.64,20.63,20.73,20.98,21.04,20.95,20.96,20.92,20.84,20.85,20.78,20.62,20.55,20.42,20.19,20.21,20.1,19.86,19.55,19.32,19.2,
    + 19.14,19.02,18.88,18.73,18.6,18.55,18.63,18.67,18.66,18.58,18.55,18.55,18.48,18.43,18.44,18.29,18.19,18.22,18.37,18.49,18.55,18.55,18.55,18.55,18.4,
    + 18.32,18.33,18.25,18.22,18.22,18.14,18.11,18.11,18.03,18,18,17.93,17.85,17.78,17.71,17.68,17.78,17.79,17.75,17.67,17.74,17.79,17.78,17.62,17.57,17.57,
    + 17.57,17.59,17.67,17.6,17.58,17.67,17.91,18.04,18.11,18.18,18.23,18.22,18.39,18.44,18.44,18.44,18.44,18.44,18.59,18.63,18.55,18.78,18.95,19.09,19.24,
    + 19.35,19.42,19.64,19.86,20.08,20.16,20.25,20.4,20.63,20.78,20.84,21.07,21.23,21.28,21.2,21.2,21.28,21.2,21.2,21.28,21.2,21.2,21.28,21.13,21.04,21.06,
    + 21.21,21.33,21.39,21.28,21.37,21.61,21.94,22.08,22.15,22.22,22.32,22.48,22.53,22.7,22.92,23.15,23.31,23.46,23.61,23.54,22.81,22.35,22.26,22.26,22.26,
    + 22.29,22.37,22.22,22.11,22.04,21.89,21.81,21.82,21.6,21.5,21.5,21.28,21.06,20.84,20.62,20.48,20.51,20.28,20.14,20.08,20.1,19.96,19.64,19.48,19.39,
    + 19.31,19.16,19.02,18.88,18.94,19,18.99,18.92,18.84,18.77,18.7,18.68,18.77,18.54,18.39,18.33,18.34,18.24,18,18.01,17.93,17.78,17.87,17.82,17.67,17.59,
    + 17.57,17.57,17.49,17.46,17.46,17.37,17.35,17.35,17.35,17.35,17.35,17.27,17.24,17.24,17.24,17.24,17.24,17.17,17.13,17.13,17.06,17.02,17.02,16.87,16.76,
    + 16.69,16.62,16.51,16.36,16.34,16.4,16.47,16.47,16.47,16.47,16.47,16.47,16.47,16.54,16.59,16.58,16.75,16.8,16.8,16.8,16.8,16.8,16.87,16.9,16.91,17.06,
    + 17.2,17.35,17.62,17.93,18.22,18.3,18.39,18.55,18.77,18.99,19.2,19.42,19.66,19.97,20.2,20.34,20.4,20.7,20.96,21.17,21.23,21.38,21.61,21.92,22.07,
    + 22.04,22.13,22.15,22.15,22.15,22.24,22.48,22.48,22.48,22.48,22.48,22.43,22.26,22.35,22.3,22.15,22.15,22.15,22.15,22.15,22.15,22.15,22.1,21.94,
    + 21.72,21.57,21.43,21.28,21.22,21.04,20.73,20.5,20.31,20.19,20.21,20.12,19.97,19.82,19.68,19.53,19.46,19.35,19.2,19.06,18.89,18.66,18.67,18.59,18.44,
    + 18.37,18.29,18.22,18.15,18.07,18,18,17.94,17.78,17.9,17.79,17.57,17.35,17.18,17.13,16.98,17.01,17.35,17.25,16.93,16.58,16.51,16.43,16.36,16.29,16.24,
    + 16.26,16.74,16.72,16.15,16.14,16.17,16.26,16.61,16.95,17.13,16.38,15.92,15.82,15.92,15.86,15.71,15.72,15.67,15.6,15.6,15.57,15.49,15.54,15.71,15.93,
    + 15.93,15.93,15.93,15.93,15.97,16.15,16.31,16.4,16.47,16.54,16.57,16.47,16.53,16.65,16.8,16.86,16.98,17.13,17.28,17.34,17.24,17.53,17.76,17.89,17.89,
    + 17.93,18,17.99,17.97,17.99,18.17,18.35,18.53,18.56,18.74,18.98,19.25,19.37,19.34,19.34,19.39,19.52,19.46,19.41,19.43,19.55,19.67,19.79,19.97,20.14,
    + 20.24,20.12,20.03,19.97,19.83,19.79,19.79,19.79,19.71,19.52,19.58,19.64,19.7,19.76,19.84,19.97,20.09,20.17,20.06,19.87,19.75,19.7,19.5,19.41,19.43,
    + 19.5,19.45,19.25,19.18,19.16,19.16,18.71,18.48,18.44,18.45,18.41,18.35,18.29,18.23,18.17,18.23,18.26,18.26,18.34,18.32,18.26,18.2,18.24,18.53,18.56,
    + 18.47,18.35,18.22,18.14,18.08,18.02,17.97,17.99,18.47,18.44,17.9,17.75,17.72,17.72,17.73,17.7,17.63,17.57,17.51,17.45,17.93,17.92,17.45,17.3,17.33,
    + 17.45,17.38,17.36,17.36,17.31,17.28,17.36,17.7,17.68,17.28,17.22,17.16,17.1,17.04,16.99,17.01,17.07,17.07,17.01,17.07,17.13,17.19,17.3,17.39,17.45,
    + 17.58,17.61,17.54,17.6,17.66,17.72,17.78,17.85,17.99,18.26,18.34,18.26,18.25,18.34,18.53,18.53,18.53,18.53,18.65,18.74,18.8,18.86,18.95,19.07,19.07,
    + 19.07,19.07,19.19,19.28,19.34,19.4,19.46,19.52,19.47,19.42,19.43,19.55,19.6,19.52,19.79,19.83,19.7,19.68,19.73,19.79,19.85,19.86,19.79,19.85,19.91,
    + 19.97,20.03,20.08,20.06,19.9,19.94,20.06,20.18,20.2,19.97,19.95,20.07,20.24,20.12,20,19.88,19.88,19.85,19.79,19.73,19.63,19.43,19.31,19.19,19.07,
    + 19.01,18.95,18.89,18.83,18.77,18.71,18.59,18.48,18.44,18.5,18.56,18.62,18.56,18.55,18.62,18.53,18.61,18.8,18.94,18.98,18.89,18.7,18.61,18.62,18.5,
    + 18.38,18.26,18.88,18.89,18.44,18.25,18.1,18.08,18.72,19.29,19.61,19.58,19.01,17.99,18.42,18.32,17.9,17.85,17.75,17.63,17.63,17.6,17.54,17.54,17.54,
    + 17.54,17.87,17.88,17.54,17.56,17.48,17.36,17.29,17.28,17.28,17.28,17.28,17.28,17.39,17.44,17.36,17.63,17.7,17.63,17.69,17.75,17.81,17.81,17.83,17.9,
    + 18.18,18.22,18.08,17.99,18.02,18.08,18.14,18.24,18.44,18.36,18.41,18.53,18.65,18.77,18.89,19.01,19.1,19.15,19.28,19.37,19.43,19.56,19.65,19.71,19.83,
    + 19.95,20.08,20.08,20.1,20.17,20.29,20.41,20.54,20.66,20.83,21.09,21.11,21.06,21,21.2,21.2,21,21.06,21.12,21.19,20.92,20.84,20.91,20.92,20.89,20.82,
    + 20.9,20.85,20.72,20.66,20.6,20.54,20.42,20.29,20.17,20.04,19.92,19.8,19.75,19.65,19.52,19.4,19.31,19.25,19,18.79,18.6,18.41,18.27,18.23,18.1,18,17.95,
    + 17.95,17.93,17.86,17.85,17.94,18.14,17.89,17.73,17.67,17.47,17.39,17.4,17.34,17.28,17.21,17.15,17.13,17.21,17.23,17.16,17.03,16.97,16.91,16.84,16.78,
    + 16.72,16.66,16.65,16.69,16.75,16.69,16.63,16.57,16.58,16.54,16.47,16.41,16.39,16.47,16.41,16.37,16.38,16.46,16.44,16.38,16.31,16.28,
    + 16.29,16.29,16.29,16.29,16.34,16.41,16.47,16.47,16.5,16.57,16.57,16.59,16.66,16.86,16.98,17.03,17.02,17.08,17.21,17.2,17.24,17.31,17.37,17.4,17.4,
    + 17.52,17.64,17.77,17.96,18.03,17.95,18.01,18.07,18.14,18.39,18.58,18.69,18.77,18.74,18.6,18.52,18.53,18.6,18.6,18.6,18.6,18.6,18.68,18.97,18.95,
    + 19.06,19.25,19.38,19.43,19.43,19.79,20.15,20.35,20.29,20.23,20.17,20.15,20.29,20.63,20.59,20.46,20.26,20.85,20.83,20.45,20.18,20.01,19.89,19.77,
    + 19.6,19.34,19.29,19.17,18.97,18.65,18.43,18.32,18.25,18.25,18.32,17.96,17.67,17.67,18.34,18.61,18.32,17.64,17.29,17.12,17,16.89,16.84,16.99,16.95,
    + 16.75,16.68,16.66,16.66,16.61,16.44,16.1,16.11,16.01,15.83,15.85,15.74,15.55,15.39,15.36,15.36,15.36,15.33,15.27,16.18,16.93,17.12,16.74,16.11,
    + 15.46,15.45,15.4,15.27,15.42,15.35,15.09,15.03,14.97,14.9,14.84,14.78,14.72,14.6,14.5,14.53,15.23,15.22,14.53,14.47,14.41,14.35,14.35,14.32,
    + 14.26,14.31,14.41,14.53,14.4,14.35,14.35,14.35,14.35,14.35,14.7,15.04,15.27,15.43,15.46,15.46,15.46,15.5,15.64,15.69,15.82,16.01,16.07,16.13,16.2,
    + 16.26,16.36,16.57,16.67,16.92,17.31,17.62,17.92,18.23,18.11,18.14,18.41,18.11,18.18,18.51,18.56,18.73,18.97,18.79,18.61,18.51,18.94,19.25,19.43,
    + 19.57,19.63,19.62,19.72,19.92,20.17,20.17,20.23,20.35,20.28,20.32,20.45,20.32,20.21,20.17,20.23,20.29,20.35,20.37,20.25,19.98,19.98,19.97,19.89,
    + 19.59,19.28,19.06,19.11,19.17,19.15,18.97,18.78,18.6,18.53,18.48,18.41,18.12,17.82,17.58,17.4,17.19,16.94,16.75,16.58,16.47,16.48,16.41,16.29,
    + 16.24,16.14,16.01,15.89,15.75,15.55,15.41,15.35,15.36,15.24,15.15,15.09,14.96,14.84,14.72,14.51,14.41,14.35,14.29,14.2,14.07,14.01,13.95,13.89,
    + 13.76,13.69,13.7,13.64,13.58,13.52,13.45,13.41,13.42,13.3,13.2,13.15,13.22,13.19,13.05,13.13,13.13,13.05,12.91,12.87,12.87,12.87,12.88,12.96,
    + 13.29,13.46,13.52,13.64,13.73,13.79,13.98,14.11,14.16,14.41,14.6,14.72,15.03,15.29,15.46,15.44,15.57,15.83,15.97,16.04,16.1,16.16,16.33,16.75,
    + 17.07,17.31,17.49,17.75,17.95,18.14,18.34,18.55,18.78,18.91,18.99,19.04,18.96,19.02,19.21,19.32,19.5,19.8,19.84,20.04,20.4,20.6,20.66,20.65,
    + 20.69,20.82,20.99,21.11,21.2,21.25,21.16,21.23,21.42,21.7,21.74,21.67,21.62,21.54,21.42,21.49,21.38,21.08,20.95,20.88,20.82,20.77,20.71,20.65,
    + 20.54,20.45,20.4,20.29,20.2,20.14,19.91,19.74,19.63,19.47,19.24,18.95,18.83,18.75,18.7,18.33,18.16,18.1,18.05,17.93,17.67,17.99,17.92,17.5,
    + 17.57,17.59,17.59,17.73,17.68,17.42,17.25,17.31,17.42,17.53,17.6,17.5,17.45,17.41,17.42,17.37,17.28,17.16,17.16,17.11,16.99,17.07,17.05,16.99,
    + 16.94,16.9,16.91,16.98,16.95,16.82,16.75,16.74,16.74,16.74,16.74,16.74,16.68,16.64,16.65,16.71,16.77,16.82,16.81,16.85,16.91,16.96,17.02,17.08,
    + 17.19,17.28,17.33,17.44,17.55,17.59,17.41,17.32,17.33,17.39,17.45,17.5,17.67,17.83,17.93,17.74,17.7,17.76,17.77,17.73,17.67,17.74,17.76,17.76,
    + 17.76,17.82,18.1,18.33,18.55,18.78,18.96,19.13,19.29,19.4,19.52,19.63,19.74,19.84,19.89,19.88,19.94,20.06,20.13,20.14,20.14,20.14,20.18,20.31,
    + 20.31,20.34,20.4,20.4,20.42,20.48,20.48,20.5,20.57,20.38,20.34,20.4,20.34,20.28,20.23,20.27,20.36,20.48,20.5,20.41,20.23,20.23,20.2,20.14,20.14,
    + 20.1,19.97,20.05,19.9,19.46,19.35,19.21,19.04,18.98,18.87,18.7,18.65,18.53,18.36,18.24,18.15,18.1,17.92,17.84,17.85,17.91,17.87,17.67,17.75,
    + 17.68,17.5,17.46,17.34,17.16,17.11,17.02,16.91,16.85,16.76,16.65,16.6,16.54,16.48,17.25,17.23,16.48,16.35,16.28,16.23,16.23,16.18,16.06,16.06,
    + 16.06,16.06,16.19,16.17,15.97,15.88,16.25,17.25,17.32,17.33,17.33,17.4,17.1,16.06,15.73,15.57,15.46,15.38,15.4,15.46,15.52,15.55,15.55,15.7,
    + 15.91,16.14,16.14,16.19,16.31,16.37,16.46,16.65,16.94,17.2,17.42,17.63,17.65,17.5,17.32,17.23,17.25,17.3,17.38,17.5,17.56,17.63,17.76,17.93,
    + 18.1,18.27,18.5,18.66,18.7,18.95,19.01,18.87,18.99,19.06,19.12,19.29,19.46,19.63,19.8,19.91,19.89,20.19,20.37,20.4,20.34,20.28,20.23,20.17,
    + 20.18,20.4,20.52,20.58,20.57,20.7,20.73,20.65,20.51,20.51,20.57,20.63,20.62,20.48,20.42,20.4,20.4,20.28,20.25,20.31,20.26,20.2,20.14,20.09,
    + 20.03,19.97,19.87,19.73,19.55,19.32,19.1,18.87,18.81,18.65,18.36,18.3,18.22,18.1,17.86,17.7,17.59,17.48,17.34,17.16,17.17,17.08,16.91,16.85,
    + 16.79,16.74,16.57,16.45,16.4,16.21,16.1,16.06,16.06,16.04,15.97,15.86,15.74,15.63,15.57,15.5,15.38,15.38,15.33,15.21,15.34,15.35,15.29,15.29,
    + 15.27,15.21,15.21,15.16,15.04,15.05,15.01,14.95,14.89,14.88,14.95,14.95,14.95,14.95,14.95,14.95,14.95,15.06,15.16,15.21,15.21,15.24,15.38,15.66,
    + 15.91,16.06,16.11,16.19,16.31,16.36,16.49,16.74,17.06,17.2,17.25,17.3,17.29,17.16,17.33,17.48,17.59,17.57,17.71,18.02,18.2,18.33,18.44,18.61,18.78,
    + 18.87,18.87,18.87,18.87,18.8,18.84,19.04,19.08,19.18,19.29,19.4,19.48,19.46,19.58,19.66,19.72,19.77,19.81,19.8,19.86,19.9,19.89,20.08,20.12,
    + 20.06,20.05,20.08,20.14,20.09,20.05,20.06,20.17,20.27,20.31,20.13,20.08,20.14,20.03,19.91,19.8,19.91,19.97,19.97,19.97,19.99,20.06,20.11,20.16,
    + 20.14,20.04,19.9,19.72,19.37,19.14,19.04,18.67,18.47,18.44,18.51,18.53,18.53,18.53,18.41,18.02,17.95,17.92,17.93,18.05,18.11,18.1,18.04,18.13,
    + 18.44,18.19,18.09,18.1,18.17,18.12,17.93,17.99)
    > 
    > y=ts(x,frequency=144)
    > library(forecast)
    > hwOut<-HoltWinters(y)
    > plot(hwOut)
```

[image]